# How to load profile images from Twitter without being tracked?

Tags: html, browser, tracking

Example:

```
<img src="https://twitter.com/mozilla/profile_image">
```

Live demo: https://jsbin.com/ziwanu/edit?html,output

The corresponding HTTP request sends cookies to Twitter, which is why Firefox’s new Tracking Protection feature blocks it, i.e. the image is not displayed. Is there a way to get profile images from Twitter in a manner compatible with Firefox’s Tracking Protection?

---

**Update:** The image proxy can be used as a dynamic fallback (via `onerror` attribute). Demo: https://jsbin.com/xibose/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I thought `crossorigin="anonymous"` would help, but then Firefox apparently does not follow the `location` redirect.

Comment: Does using a service like Avatars IO work?  For example http://avatars.io/twitter/mozilla - it does redirect to http://pbs.twimg.com though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can chain a couple of things together to do this...

Using Avatars.io you can request a user's image without asking Twitter.

http://avatars.io/twitter/mozilla

Or, for a larger image

http://avatars.io/twitter/mozilla?size=large

That will redirect to

http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/576067580219146242/ON0VuHtK_bigger.png

I don't know if your cookies will get sent there.  If they do, you can use an image proxy like https://images.weserv.nl/ (Other proxies are available!).

So - https://images.weserv.nl/?url=avatars.io%2Ftwitter%2Fmozilla%3Fsize%3Dlarge

That will load the image via the proxy - without sending anything to Twitter, I think.

Comment: I’ve made a [demo](https://jsbin.com/rozime/edit?html,output) which contains all the different methods of requesting the image (for debugging). Tracking Protection blocks everything except the image proxy URL. I’ve looked at the request headers, but wasn’t able to pinpoint the headers that cause Tracking Protection to behave the way it does.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox apparently has a black list of domains that it on a network level won't allow a third-party website to when browsing privately: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Privacy/Tracking_Protection

So the only way to load a profile image from Twitter when in private browsing mode would be to proxy it through another server I guess.